global directives: autofocus not working in Vuejs 3
Please, tell me why it raised the error like this
Note.vue:11 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive: autofocus 
  at <Note key="1" note= {id: '1', content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing…riosam a, quos, amet animi, esse id nobis vel ad.'} onDeleteClicked=fn<handleDeleteClicked> > 
  at <ViewNotes onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< undefined > > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App>

I declared the directive component
src/directives/vAutofocus.js
export const vAutofocus = {
  mounted: (el) => {
    el.focus();
  },
};

I used in other component
src/view/AddEditNote.vue
<template>
    <textarea type="text" placeholder="Type something ..." v-autofocus />
<template>
<script setup>
    import { vAutofocus } from "@/directives/vAutofocus"
</script>

I'm follow the tutorial on Udemy, I also try to search but I have not find anything yet.
Thanks a lot!
Update:
I provide my architecture code:

Error:


The code where you used it is cut, please provide the full version.

I provided two path: where it declare and where it used.

@happy you should provide a minimum reproducible example, it's hard to understand what's wrong, maybe your @ is wrong, try @src/directives/...

@Mohammadsiabbou ,@AlexanderNesashev I updated more information.

I tried to recreate the bug, but I couldn't, it's working fire for me, please try putting the script before the template, if it doesn't work share a link to the repository with me so that I try fixing it from there.

@Mohammadsiabbou it's not work for me, my code is available in here

The code is working ok for me ! Please make sure it is not a cache related issue or something, sorry I couldn't help you.

Warning in the console of chrome. Do you see that?

This could be due to the autofocus directive not being registered globally.
In Vue 3, you can register a directive globally during the creation of the Vue app instance. I'm not sure if you've done it but here's an example:
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import { vAutofocus } from "@/directives/vAutofocus"

const app = createApp(App)

app.directive('autofocus', vAutofocus)

app.mount('#app')

Try to import the vAutofocus directive and register it globally using app.directive(). The v-autofocus directive should be available in all components.

Thanks, I only want to import in the component that I will use
